# Windows 10 want duplicate-ish start menu items

Tags: windows, start-menu

I'm trying to pin multiple shortcuts to the same program (exe) but different arguments to the start menu and Windows refuses to show more than 1 item.

Is there a way to trick windows into showing my shortcuts?

using windows 10.

Comment: Change the shortcut name.

Comment: @Biswa doesn't work.  i suspect it is matching the target executable name.

Comment: Copy the shortcuts in these two folder `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` and `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` both.

Comment: @Biswa nope.  and i even tried to make a app.exe and app1.exe and it STILL doesn't want 2 shortcuts.  this is annoying.

Comment: Related: [Pin same app multiple times in Windows 7](https://superuser.com/q/255312/376602).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 Start Menu can't have multiple shortcuts with the same target](https://superuser.com/questions/1280211/windows-10-start-menu-cant-have-multiple-shortcuts-with-the-same-target)